# Excel: get value between characters, but if empty copy cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the formula below to get a value between the the first and second "|".
However sometimes there is no value. The formula will result in #VALUE!
So, is it possible to get the value between the first and second "|" character, but if there is no value, copy the whole cell?

The formula i use is:    `=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B2;FIND("|";SUBSTITUTE(B2;"|";"|";2))+1;LEN(B2));"|";REPT(" ";LEN(B2)));LEN(B2)))`

The result i would like is:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Collected      |       Data       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Value 2       |  Value|Value 2   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Value         |      Value       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I guess this needs a module?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `IFERROR()`?

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(G2;FIND("|";SUBSTITUTE(G2;"|";"|";2))+1;LEN(G2));"|";REPT(" ";LEN(G2)));LEN(G2))),TRIM(G2))
```